# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while running maven project in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

This is the Stack trace tree , I am getting while running my maven project in Jenkins. I don't understand what is the problem with my code, maybe it is because of some plugins in Jenkins.

```
    <===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f /home/app/JavaEclipse/SampleMavenTest/pom.xml clean compile test
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main.launch(Maven33Main.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:139)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:332)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_USER_SETTINGS_FILE
    at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.settings(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:658)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.getMavenExecutionRequest(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:149)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven33Launcher.getMavenExecutionRequest(Maven33Launcher.java:150)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven33Launcher.main(Maven33Launcher.java:127)
    ... 21 more
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
channel stopped
```

Comment: Problem is `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_USER_SETTINGS_FILE
`. Looks like incompatible Version of maven libs

Comment: It is a Jenkins bug: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43446 ? https://github.com/jenkinsci/maven-interceptors/pull/11

Comment: It works completely fine by changing maven 3.5.0 to its older version. Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: You are welcome