# Not able to launch my maven automation project through Jenkins , Getting InvocationTargetException exception

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am using below configuration,

OS Windows : 10 
Java:1.8.121
Maven:3.5.0
Jenkins: 2.59

I got below Exception when I start my job:

```
Building in workspace C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\MavenDemo
       Parsing POMs
       Established TCP socket on 54681
       [com.cucumber.decos] $ "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java" -cp "C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven33-agent-1.8.1.jar;D:\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.0\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;D:\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.0/conf/logging"
   jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main D:\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.0
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-3.7.jar"
   "C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven33-interceptor-1.8.1.jar"
   "C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.8.1.jar"
   54681
       <===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
       Executing Maven:  -B -f D:\17Q1\com.cucumber.decos\pom.xml compile
       java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
        at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main.launch(Maven33Main.java:176)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:139)
        at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
        at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
        at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
       Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_USER_SETTINGS_FILE
        at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.settings(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:658)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.getMavenExecutionRequest(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:149)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven33Launcher.getMavenExecutionRequest(Maven33Launcher.java:150)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven33Launcher.main(Maven33Launcher.java:127)
        ... 21 more
       ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
       java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:179)
        at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
        at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
        at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at ......remote call to Channel to Maven [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java, -cp, C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven33-agent-1.8.1.jar;D:\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.0\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;D:\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.0/conf/logging,
   jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main, D:\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.0,
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-3.7.jar,
   C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven33-interceptor-1.8.1.jar,
   C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.8.1.jar,
   54681](Native Method)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1545)
        at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:253)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:830)
        at hudson.maven.ProcessCache$MavenProcess.call(ProcessCache.java:161)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:873)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:544)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:139)
        at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
        at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
        at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
       Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main.launch(Maven33Main.java:179)
        ... 14 more
       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
        at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main.launch(Maven33Main.java:176)
        ... 14 more
       Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_USER_SETTINGS_FILE
        at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.settings(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:658)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.getMavenExecutionRequest(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:149)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven33Launcher.getMavenExecutionRequest(Maven33Launcher.java:150)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven33Launcher.main(Maven33Launcher.java:127)
        ... 21 more
       channel stopped
       Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: add the complete exception and all relevant configurations

Comment: Jenkins needs at least JDK 8. Maven 3.5.0 needs at least JDK 7...

Comment: I have changed my Java Version to JDK 8

Comment: @Jens  Please look into exception

Comment: @PavanT it is a Jenkins bug: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43446

Comment: @PavanT also see the comments at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43675711/java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception-while-running-maven-project-in-jenki

Comment: I have downgrade maven from 3.5 to 3.1 and it's working for me now.